# "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" when AutoLayout is disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have disabled Auto Layout in the interface builder for a specific view:
[image: Interface builder]

But I get this error in the console, when I load the ViewController for the xib file:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>
> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

I am working with frames in this view and I usually don't get any Auto Layout errors when I have disabled it in the Interface Builder. This is the constraints that seems to break:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170f5cd0 V:[UIView:0x1709e560]-(0)-[UITableView:0x162e2200]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17185130 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x1709e560.midY == + 48>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x157e29a0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x1709e560(96)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x171c2670 h=--& v=--& TableHeaderView:0x1705d1c0.midY == + 72.5>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x171cb510 h=--& v=--& V:[TableHeaderView:0x1705d1c0(145)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1573fca0 h=-&- v=-&- UITableView:0x162e2200.midY == UIView:0x17505080.midY + 72.5>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1573fcd0 h=-&- v=-&- UITableView:0x162e2200.height == UIView:0x17505080.height - 145>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x171e4450 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x17505080]   (Names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x17034d00 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16c9ad30 V:[UIView:0x16cc2a00]-(0)-[UITableView:0x15249400]>
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but I only thought I would be getting this error if Auto Layout was enabled?

To me it seems like it thinks I have setup a constraint between the `UIView` and the `UITableView`, but I havn't! Auto Layout is disabled in the Interface Builder and I do not set any constraints in the code.

I have tried setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`, but my frames are not respected when I do this.

It seems to me, like the view is working with Auto Layout. I have tried to delete the file and construct it again, but I still get the same error.

Why am I getting this error when Auto Layout is disabled in the xib file?

**EDIT:**

It turns out that I had made a mistake when I was searching for constraints. I found this line in my code:

```
NSDictionary* views = @{@"searchHeaderView": self.searchHeader.view, @"tableView": self.tableView};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[searchHeaderView]-(==0)-[tableView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

I think that explains it :-P

Comment: Auto layout is enabled if **any** views in your view hierarchy have constraints. If auto layout is enabled, the springs'n'struts in your XIB are converted to constraints (of type `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`).

Comment: Also, I suspect there is more output in the debugger console. If there is, please edit your question to include everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something weird is going on, because if you look closely, the memory addresses of at the 'will break' constraint and views attached to it are not in the array, so these are different instances.

Regardless, the unwelcome Auto Layout behavior is consistent with your suspicion: If one constraint gets added to the view hierarchy, AutoLayout "turns back on" at least for for that part of it and you get a mess of autoresizingmask constraints.

So this is a debugging issue. Some commands methods you can use in the debugger:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

Gives you a complete outline of the view hierarchy, with UIView descriptions, which include frames.

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

This is private API but that's not an issue during development and especially not debugging. This actually works best if you follow the suggestion and add a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints (the breakpoints navigator, at the bottom). Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It turned out that I actually did create the constraint myself. Sorry :-/ But +1 for the `_autolayoutTrace`.

Comment: @ThomasClemensen So my statement "this is a debugging issue" was correct, as was "...behavior is consistent with your suspicion. If one constraint is added...", and you said you appreciate one of the debugging tools mentioned. Seems like you could mark this as accepted. Creating your own answer to accept just to provide the exact line of code adding more constraints -- which you specifically said "I haven't!" -- isn't very courteous to someone who took a serious look at your problem with the information you provided.

Comment: I actually tried to delete the question, because no one can use this for anything since I was providing wrong information. When I tried to delete it StackOverflow told me it was a **very bad idea**. But since you are crying I fixed it for you.

Comment: Actually I think it is a decent question, and how to identify what's causing this problem (as opposed to being a misunderstand of autolayout) is the answer. And I am trying to build stats, so I appreciate you accepted it. Auto Layout is a minefield a lot of the time, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that if you do not want to use AutoLayout then you need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `YES` rather than `NO`.

This then ensures that constraints are created for you which reflect the position drawn in interface builder without you having to add constraints. Perhaps you have some constraints assigned which clash with those it thinks it needs to autogenerate? I would remove any constraints, if you can find any. If there are none to delete, can you post the list it says are clashing?

Comment: It could be a leftover layout resource on the device/simulator. I have had layout issues before which could only be fixed by uninstalling the app and then running it.  Worth a try first.